# Remove tags with same key with tags input jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

Using bootstrap tags input jquery https://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/

I'm stuggling to achieve something.

First I add a tag like so:

```
 $('.tag_in').tagsinput('add', {text: 'Over 30 minutes', type: 'format'});
```

But I only want to allow one tag with the type 'format'. So ideally, if another tag with type format is added, I would do something like that:

```
$('.tag_in').tagsinput('remove', {type: 'format'});
```

But that doesn't work as I have to specify the text value (which is a variable).

Any help would be great as I have been struggling to find a solution for this.